# Server side notification when action cable disconnects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

If you change a Rails application file (say a view), then you make a request on the server (i.e. API HTTP request) ActionCable drops any actioncable (websocket) connections.

The connection will be automatically re-established in about 7 seconds but if any messages are sent during this time they will be dropped.

Soooo the question is is there any way to get a notification on the server that the connection is being dropped?  That way the server application can internally queue up messages until the connections are re-established.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I did not.  We ended up using pusher.com for production.  Its cheap and I think more reliable (just my opinion)